# How run makeindex inside memoir class document for glossary?

Tags: memoir, glossaries, indexing

How can one run `makeindex`from within a `memoir` documentclass source so as to create a glossary?

**For a glossary, calling `makeindex` (via the `imakeidx` package) fails with `memoir`.**

Here is my source, which calls `makeindex` (via the `imakeidx` package) seemingly using the syntax as described in Section 17.3 of `memman.pdf`.

When I run a pdflatex make file on the source (from within TeXShop, via the pdflatexmk engine), I get the following error:

```
Rule 'cusdep goo gas book': File changes, etc:
   Non-existent destination files:
     'book.gls
```

The source:

```
% BOOK.TEX

\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[makeindex]{imakeidx}
\makeglossary
\makeindex[options=-s glossarystyle.gst,-o book.gls book.glo]

\begin{document}

The empty set is denoted by $\emptyset$.%
\glossary{$\emptyset$}{empty set}

The set of all subsets of a set $X$ is denoted by $\mathcal{P}(X)$.%
\glossary{$\mathcal{P}(X)$}{power set of set}

\newpage

For sets $X$ and $Y$, the notation $f \colon X \to Y$ means that $f$ is a functions from $X$ to $Y$.%
\glossary{$f \colon X \to Y$}{functions from one set to another}.

\printglossary

\end{document}
```

The referenced style file `glossarystyle.gst:

```
% GLOSSARYSTYLE.GST
%%% basic.gst basic makindex glossary style file
 %%% Output style parameters
 preamble "\\begin{theglossary}"
 postamble "\n\\end{theglossary}\n"
 item_0    "\n\\glossitem"
 delim_0   "{\\memglonum{"
 encap_suffix "}}}"
 headings_flag 1
 heading_prefix "\\doglobookmark{"
 heading_suffix "}"
 %%% Input style parameters
 keyword "\\glossaryentry"
```

Note that I am using just the built-in glossary facilities of the `memoir` class, and *not* the external package `glossaries`!

the `latexmkrc` file being called by the TeXShop.app's built-in pdflatexmk engine is:

```
# latexmkrcedit
# Edit this File to add/change dependencies and rules
# The following is used by ALL the latexmk engine files

# change the empty string ,'', to '--shell-escape' to add the shell-escape default
$TSUserCompileOptions = '';
#$TSUserCompileOptions = '--shell-escape';

# turn recorder option off (no .fls file generated)
#$recorder=0;

# Custom dependency for glossary/glossaries package
# if you make custom glossaries you may have to add items to the @cus_dep_list and corresponding sub-routines
add_cus_dep('glo', 'gls', 0, 'makeglo2gls');
        sub makeglo2gls {
                system("makeindex -s '$_[0]'.ist -t '$_[0]'.glg -o '$_[0]'.gls '$_[0]'.glo");
        }
# The glossaries package, with the [acronym] option, produces a .acn file when processed with (xe/pdf)latex and
# then makeindex to process the .acn into .acr and finally runs of (xe/pdf)latex to read in the .acr file. Unfortunately
# the glossary package does just the reverse; i.e. (xe/pdf)latex processing produces a .acr files and makeindex then
# is used to convert the .acr file to a .acn file which is then ... . This dependency assumes the glossaries package.
add_cus_dep('acn', 'acr', 0, 'makeacn2acr');
        sub makeacn2acr {
                system("makeindex -s '$_[0]'.ist -t '$_[0]'.alg -o '$_[0]'.acr '$_[0]'.acn");
        }
# for glossary package (Sigh...) --- they can co-exist!     
add_cus_dep('acr', 'acn', 0, 'makeacr2acn');
        sub makeacr2acn {
                system("makeindex -s '$_[0]'.ist -t '$_[0]'.alg -o '$_[0]'.acn '$_[0]'.acr");
        }
# example of an added custom glossary type that is used in some of the glossary/glossaries example files:
# this is for the new glossary type command \newglossary[nlg]{notation}{not}{ntn}{Notation} from the glossaries package
# NOTE: the glossary package uses a very different command: the <in-ext> and <out-ext>
# are reversed in the calling sequence :-(
add_cus_dep('ntn', 'not', 0, 'makentn2not');
        sub makentn2not {
                system("makeindex -s '$_[0]'.ist -t '$_[0]'.nlg -o '$_[0]'.not '$_[0]'.ntn");
        }
# for the   glossary package (Sigh...) --- they can co-exist!
add_cus_dep('not', 'ntn', 0, 'makenot2ntn');
        sub makenot2ntn {
                system("makeindex -s '$_[0]'.ist -t '$_[0]'.nlg -o '$_[0]'.ntn '$_[0]'.not");
        }

# dependencies for custom indexes using the index package
# examples for sample.tex for index package:
 add_cus_dep('adx', 'and', 0, 'makeadx2and');
        sub makeadx2and {
                system("makeindex -o '$_[0]'.and '$_[0]'.adx");
        }
 add_cus_dep('ndx', 'nnd', 0, 'makendx2nnd');
        sub makendx2nnd {
                system("makeindex -o '$_[0]'.nnd '$_[0]'.ndx");
        }
 add_cus_dep('ldx', 'lnd', 0, 'makeldx2lnd');
     sub makeldx2lnd {
             system("makeindex -o '$_[0]'.lnd '$_[0]'.ldx");
     }

# Custom dependency and function for nomencl package
add_cus_dep('nlo', 'nls', 0, 'makenlo2nls');
        sub makenlo2nls {
                system("makeindex -s nomencl.ist -o '$_[0]'.nls '$_[0]'.nlo");
        }
```

And in turn the pdflatexmk engine is the script file:

```
#!/bin/bash
# pdflatexmk.engine
#
export TSBIN="$HOME/Library/TeXShop/bin/tslatexmk"
export LTMKBIN="$HOME/Library/TeXShop/bin/tslatexmk"
export LTMKEDIT="$HOME/Library/TeXShop/bin"
# make sure latexmkrcedit exists in bin
if [ ! -e "${LTMKEDIT}/latexmkrcedit" ] ; then
    cp "${TSBIN}/latexmkrcDONTedit" "${LTMKEDIT}/latexmkrcedit"
fi
# Use local rc file platexmkrc if it exists. p = project
export localrc=""
if [ -e ./platexmkrc ] ; then
    export localrc="-r ./platexmkrc"
fi
"${LTMKBIN}"/latexmk -pdf -r "${LTMKEDIT}/latexmkrcedit" -r "${TSBIN}/pdflatexmkrc" ${localrc} "$1"
```

**For an ordinary index, calling `makeindex` (via the `imakeidx` package) *does* work with `memoir`**.

For example, the following *does* produce an index:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[makeindex]{imakeidx}
\makeindex[options=-s indexheaders]
%%\makeglossary
%%\makeindex[options=-s glossarystyle.gst -o book.gls book.glo]

\begin{document}

The empty set is denoted by $\emptyset$.%
\index{empty set!notation}
%%\glossary{$\emptyset$}{empty set}

The set of all subsets of a set $X$ is denoted by $\mathcal{P}(X)$.%
\index{power set}
%%\glossary{$\mathcal{P}(X)$}{power set of set}

\newpage

For sets $X$ and $Y$, the notation $f \colon X \to Y$ means that $f$ is a functions from $X$ to $Y$.%
\index{function!notation}
%%\glossary{$f \colon X \to Y$}{functions from one set to another}.

\printindex
%%\printglossary

\end{document}
```

Here the referenced index style file `indexheaders.ist` is:

```
headings_flag 1
heading_prefix "{\\medskip\\hfill\\large\\textsf{\\textbf{"
heading_suffix "}}\\hfill}\\medskip\\nopagebreak\n"
```

**New try: no error but no glossary**

I changed the source file line

```
 \makeindex[options=-s glossarystyle.gst,-o book.gls book.glo]
```

to

```
\makeindex[name=glossary,title=Index of notation,options=-s glossarystyle.gst -o book.gls book.glo]
```

and changed each `\glossary` command so as to add optional file name (`glossary`), e.g.:

```
glossary[glossary]{$\emptyset$}{empty set}
```

Now when I run TeXShop's pdflatexmk engine, it generates no errors -- but no glossary at all!  It generates the expected `glossary.glo` file with the several `\glossaryentry` commands, but the `glossary.gls` file is empty.

**Solution!**

Thanks to help from Herb Schulz on the macosx-tex mailing list and privately, the following solves the problem while still using only the internal glossary facility of `memoir`, without the `glossaries` package.

The corrected source:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\from}{\mathpunct{:}}
%\newcommand{\from}{\protect\colon}
%\newcommand{\from}{:}

\makeglossary[glossary]
\renewcommand*{\glossaryname}{Index of Notation}

\makeindex

\begin{document}

The empty set is denoted by $\emptyset$.%
\index{empty set!notation}
\glossary[glossary]{$\emptyset$}{empty set}

The set of all subsets of a set $X$ is denoted by $\mathcal{P}(X)$.%
\index{power set}
\glossary[glossary]{$\mathcal{P}(X)$}{power set of set}

\newpage
$f \from X \to Y$
For sets $X$ and $Y$, the notation $f \from X \to Y$ means that $f$ is a functions from $X$ to $Y$.%
\index{function!notation}
\glossary[glossary]{$f \from X \to Y$}{function from one set to another}

\printglossary[glossary]
\printindex

\end{document}
```

Indeed, with TeXShop there is no need for `imakeidx`. The source is processed from within TeXShop using its `pdflatexmk` engine and the following additional file `platexmkrc` placed in the source directory:

```
add_cus_dep('glo', 'gls', 0, 'makeglo2gls');
    sub makeglo2gls {
            system("makeindex -s basic.gst -t '$_[0]'.glg -o '$_[0]'.gls '$_[0]'.glo");
    };
```

(For completeness: the three `\newcommand{\from}...` versions shown are ways of avoiding an error with the math relation `\colon` in the argument to `\glosary`, without having to work around an error in `\@@glossary`, per [Extra '@' in glossary entry with memoir class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/321815/extra-in-glossary-entry-with-memoir-class/321820#321820) .)

Comment: Is there supposed to be a comma after `-s glossarystyle.gst` (in `\makeindex`)? It doesn't look right, but I might be wrong. It looks as though you're creating the glossary files both through `\write18` and `pdflatexmk`, which might be confusing things.

Comment: I wondered about the comma separator in the options, so I also tried deleting it. Same error.

Comment: Do you have any reason to think this is supposed to be possible? I don't know Memoir well, but there's no obvious indication that `imakeidx` is supported on first glance through section 17.3 of the manual.

Comment: The error message looks like it's coming from `pdflatexmk` not from TeX (or `memoir`). Do you have extra code for `latexmk` in a `.latexmkrc` file?

Comment: @cfr: The `memoir` class *does* support using `imakeidx` in order to be able to call `makeindex` from within the source `.tex` file. I'll edit my post to indicate how that works.

Comment: What's the reason of using `\makeglossary`, `\glossary` and `\printglossary` instead of the “index” commands? Anyway, `imakeidx` only calls `makeindex` on `.idx` files and `\printglossary` is not supported.

Comment: @murray Yes. But there's no suggestion in either Memoir's manual or `imakeidx`'s documentation that this is supposed to work with `.glo`, `.gls`, `\makeglossary`, `\printglossary` etc.

Comment: @egreg Presumably the idea is to use Memoir's custom support for glossaries? But I don't think this can work with `imakeidx`, can it? You can use `imakeidx` index files, but if you need a distinct glossary of the `.glo`/`.gls` kind, don't you have to issue commands separately?

Comment: @cfr No, it can't work; `memoir` writes the `.glo` file at end document. Indeed, also `imakeidx` reverts the behavior for `.idx` files to be written during the run, rather than at end document, when `memoir` is being used.

Comment: are you aware of the noidx option with the glossary package ?

Comment: @Elad Den: I don't find any `glossary.sty` in TeX Live 2016, but do find the `glossaries.sty` package. Nowhere in the docs for the latter, or for the `memoir` class built-in glossary apparatus do I find any `noidx` option. In docs for `glossaries.sty` I do find commands `\makenoidxglossaries` and `\printnoidxglossaries`, but when I latex the first example, on page 4 of `glossariesbegin.pdf`, I see no glossary whatsoever in the resulting pdf.

Comment: I meant the '\makenoidxglossaries'. Did you try it with memoir ? Because i useu it all the time without fail

Comment: @Elad Den : Are you referring to the `glossaries` package, or the built-in glossary capability of `memoir`?

Comment: The glossaries package

Comment: @EladDen I think that's muddling things. This series of questions is not about using that package. (I don't know why, but I guess the OP doesn't like it or something. In any case, the project is to make shift with what Memoir itself provides, as I understand it.)

Comment: I don't dislike the `glossaries` package. But I wanted to use the glossary facility built into `memoir` to avoid any incompatibilities. (And not having to load additional code never hurts!)

Answer (score 3):

The error message

```
Rule 'cusdep goo gas book': File changes, etc:
```

looks like a message from (pdf)`latexmk` (not a TeX message). This suggests there's a rule for `latexmk` along the lines of

```
add_cus_dep('goo', 'gas', 0, 'something');
```

This doesn't really make sense as your document isn't writing or reading any files with those extensions, so it seems like something's confusing `latexmk`, but there's nothing in the code you've posted that explains it (as far as I can tell). The rest of the error message:

```
   Non-existent destination files:
     'book.gls
```

is suggesting that it's expecting the file `book.gls` to exist, but with `memoir`, the `.gls` file is the file that's dependent on the `.glo` file. You can tell this from the transcript (`book.log`) file which contains the line:

```
Writing glossary file book.glo
```

This is the file that contains the glossary information for `makeindex` to process. A little later in the transcript is another line:

```
No file book.gls.
```

This is the file that's read in by `\printglossary` and is the file that `makeindex` needs to create.

So the full build sequence is:

```
pdflatex book
makeindex -s glossarystyle.gst -o book.gls book.glo
pdflatex book
```

This is what `pdflatexmk` ought to be doing if the dependencies were set up correctly, but it seems that something has muddled them.

You can invoke `makeindex` using TeX's shell escape, which is what you seem to be trying to do with `imakeidx`, but as @egreg pointed out in the comments, that can't be done in this situation.

Instead you can explicitly use the shell escape with `\write18`. Like this:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\immediate\write18{makeindex -s glossarystyle.gst -o \jobname.gls \jobname.glo}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeglossary

\begin{document}

The empty set is denoted by $\emptyset$.%
\glossary{$\emptyset$}{empty set}

The set of all subsets of a set $X$ is denoted by $\mathcal{P}(X)$.%
\glossary{$\mathcal{P}(X)$}{power set of set}

\newpage

For sets $X$ and $Y$, the notation $f \colon X \to Y$ means that $f$
is a functions from $X$ to $Y$.%
\glossary{$f \colon X \to Y$}{functions from one set to another}.

\printglossary

\end{document}
```

Note that `\immediate` is needed here to ensure that `makeindex` is run before `\makeglossary` overwrites the `.glo` file. Now you just need:

```
pdflatex book
pdflatex book
```

This causes a couple of errors for your test file: `\doglobookmark` is undefined (I'm assuming you simply omitted it from your test file) and `makeindex` reports an error (transcript in `book.ilg`):

```
!! Input index error (file = test.glo, line = 3):
   -- Extra `@' at position 106 of first argument.
```

This is caused by the premature expansion of `\colon`, which has already been dealt with in another question.

Comment: That method, using `\write18`, does not work for me from within TeXShop. A solution that does is described in there "Solution" section of my original post.

Comment: @murray If you've found a solution, you ought to post it as an answer to get the question off the unanswered list. (You can self-answer your own questions.) The `\write18` solution won't work if the shell escape has been disabled.