# How call makeindex to create glossary with memoir class?

Tags: memoir, glossaries, indexing

What exactly is the precise call to `makeindex` in order to create a glossary from a `.tex` source that uses the `memoir` class — but *without* using the `glossaries` package?

Assume, of course, that the source includes the requisite `\makeglossary` and `\printglossary` commands along with syntactically correct `\glossary` entries. And assume one has a `.gst` file such as shown in Section 17.3 of `memman.pdf`.

(This is a more basic issue involved in the post [How run makeindex inside memoir class document for glossary?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/321597/how-run-makeindex-inside-memoir-class-document-for-glossary).

Comment: Is there any point to this question given http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/321815/extra-in-glossary-entry-with-memoir-class?

Comment: I can't see how this question is significantly different from the one you've referenced. Surely the answer is the same to both questions.

Answer (score 0):

> From the Glossaries guide for begginers

1. If you are using `ngerman` or some other package that makes the double-quote character " a shorthand, then use `\GlsSetQuote` to change this to some other character. For example:
   `\GlsSetQuote{+}`
   Use this as soon as possible after you’ve loaded the glossaries package.
2. Add `\makeglossaries` to your preamble (before you start defining your entries).
3. Put

   \printglossary[⟨options⟩]

where you want your list of entries (glossary) to appear. (The sort key isn’t available in ⟨options⟩.) Alternatively, use

```
\printglossaries
```

which will display all glossaries (if you have more than one). This command doesn’t have any arguments.

4. Run LATEX on your document. This creates files with the extensions .glo and .ist (for example, if your LATEX document is called myDoc.tex, then you’ll have two extra files called myDoc.glo and myDoc.ist). If you look at your document at this point, you won’t see the glossary as it hasn’t been created yet.
   Run makeindex with the .glo file as the input file and the .ist file as the style so that it creates an output file with the extension .gls. If you have access to a terminal or a command prompt (for example, the MSDOS command prompt for Windows users or the bash console for Unix-like users) then you need to run the command:

   makeindex -s myDoc.ist -o myDoc.gls myDoc.glo

(Replace myDoc with the base name of your LATEX document file. Avoid spaces in the file name.) If you don’t know how to use the command prompt, then you can probably access makeindex via your text editor, but each editor has a different method of doing this, so I can’t give a general description. You will have to check your editor’s manual.

The default sort is word order (“sea lion” comes before “seal”). If you want letter ordering you need to add the -l switch:

```
makeindex -l -s myDoc.ist -o myDoc.gls myDoc.glo
```

Comment: What is `[<options>]` if not an argument? In any case, aren't these instructions for the `glossaries` package and so irrelevant here? Also, if you are attributing these instructions, please provide a link. Where can I find the `Glossaries guide for beginners`? (Or is it really `begginers`?)