# Extra '@' in glossary entry with memoir class

Tags: memoir, glossaries, indexing

The following `memoir` class source file, when processed with `pdflatex` and `makeindex`, using the `memoir` class `basic.gst` glossary style file, produces a glossary that is missing the 3rd entry (about "function from one set to another"):

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeglossary[glossary]

\begin{document}

The empty set is denoted by $\emptyset$.%
\glossary[glossary]{$\emptyset$}{empty set}

The set of all subsets of a set $X$ is denoted by $\mathcal{P}(X)$.%
\glossary[glossary]{$\mathcal{P}(X)$}{power set of set}

\newpage

For sets $X$ and $Y$, the notation $f \colon X \to Y$ means that $f$ is a functions from $X$ to $Y$.%
\glossary[glossary]{$f \colon X \to Y$}{function from one set to another}

\printglossary[glossary]

\end{document}
```

The generated `glossary.glo` has as its 3rd, and last, entry:

```
\glossaryentry{$f \penalty \@M \mskip 2mu\mathpunct {}\nonscript \mkern -\thinmuskip {:}\mskip 6muplus1mu\relax X \to Y$@ {\memgloterm{$f \penalty \@M \mskip 2mu\mathpunct {}\nonscript \mkern -\thinmuskip {:}\mskip 6muplus1mu\relax X \to Y$}}{\memglodesc{function from one set to another}} {\memgloref{}}|memjustarg}{2}
```

However, the generated `glossary.gls` contains no corresponding entry.

The log file `glossary.glg` includes:

```
...Scanning input file glossary.glo....
!! Input index error (file = glossary.glo, line = 3):
   -- Extra `@' at position 106 of first argument.
done (2 entries accepted, 1 rejected).
Sorting entries....done (2 comparisons).....
```

How can this problem be fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug in the definition of `\@@glossary`, which does `\@sanitize` after having absorbed its arguments, so defeating its purpose.

So long as you don't use `\glossary` in the argument to another command, you can use a different definition that doesn't do expansion of commands:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{xparse}

\makeglossary[glossary]

\makeatletter
\RenewDocumentCommand{\glossary}{O{\jobname}d()vv}{%
  \@bsphack
  \@ifundefined{#1memglofile}{\@esphack}
   {%
    \def\memglofile{#1}%
    \begingroup
    \IfNoValueTF{#2}
      {\@wrglom@m{#3}{#3}{#4}}
      {\@wrglom@m{#2}{#3}{#4}}
   }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

The empty set is denoted by $\emptyset$.%
\glossary[glossary]{$\emptyset$}{empty set}

The set of all subsets of a set $X$ is denoted by $\mathcal{P}(X)$.%
\glossary[glossary]{$\mathcal{P}(X)$}{power set of set}

\newpage

For sets $X$ and $Y$, the notation $f \colon X \to Y$ means that 
$f$ is a functions from $X$ to $Y$.%
\glossary[glossary]{$f \colon X \to Y$}{function from one set to another}

\printglossary[glossary]

\end{document}
```

Alternative solution: redefine `\@wrglom@m`

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\makeglossary[glossary]

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@wrglom@m}[3]{%
  \protected@write\@auxout{}{%
    \string\@@wrglom@m
      {\memglofile}%
      {\unexpanded{\unexpanded{#1}}}%
      {\unexpanded{\unexpanded{#2}}}%
      {\unexpanded{\unexpanded{#3}}}%
      {\@nameuse{memglsnx\memglofile}}{\@nameuse{memglsn\memglofile}}%
  }%
  \endgroup
  \@esphack
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

The empty set is denoted by $\emptyset$.%
\glossary[glossary]{$\emptyset$}{empty set}

The set of all subsets of a set $X$ is denoted by $\mathcal{P}(X)$.%
\glossary[glossary]{$\mathcal{P}(X)$}{power set of set}

\newpage

For sets $X$ and $Y$, the notation $f \colon X \to Y$ means that 
$f$ is a functions from $X$ to $Y$.%
\glossary[glossary]{$f \colon X \to Y$}{function from one set to another}

\printglossary[glossary]

\end{document}
```

Comment: The alternative solution, just to redefine `\@wrglom@m` also takes care of other problematic uses of `memoir`s `\glossary` when the first argument is a math expression in turn containing a math operator that takes an argument (with `{` and `}`).

Answer (score 3):

You just need to `\protect` the problematic macros which use `@`s in their definitions.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeglossary[glossary]

\begin{document}

The empty set is denoted by $\emptyset$.%
\glossary[glossary]{$\emptyset$}{empty set}

The set of all subsets of a set $X$ is denoted by $\mathcal{P}(X)$.%
\glossary[glossary]{$\mathcal{P}(X)$}{power set of set}

\newpage

For sets $X$ and $Y$, the notation $f \colon X \to Y$ means that $f$ is a functions from $X$ to $Y$.%
\glossary[glossary]{$f \protect\colon X \protect\to Y$}{function from one set to another}

\printglossary[glossary]

\end{document}
```

[image: glossary with protections]

Answer (score 0):

Herb Schulz pointed out to me that the underlying problem is that `\colon` is a relational command.

An easy workaround that still gives smaller space to the left of the actual colon than does `\colon` seems to be to define

```
\newcommand{\from}{\mathpunct{:}}
```

and then use, e.g.:

```
$f \from X \to Y$
```

both in the body of the text and in a corresponding `\glossary` item.

I'm unsure of which produces the more satisfactory spacing around the actual colon from the point of view of mathematical style --  `\newcommand{\from}{\mathpunct{:}}` or `\newcommand{\from}{\protect\colon}`. (Any thoughts?)